# Location of virtualenv in production

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm in the process of deploying a Django site, and I'm using a virtualenv to keep my Python installation tidy.  I'm trying to figure out where the virtual environment should be located in a production server environment.  It seems like this should be super straightforward, but it's giving me a monster headache.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My plan was to use virtualenvwrapper to make my virtual environment.  By default, this stores the virtualenv in `~/.virtualenvs`, which in this case is `/home/james/virtualenvs/`.  This is fine in development, when I'm on my local machine and running everything under the user `james`.  However, I don't believe that the user `james` is going to be running the code in the virtualenv on the production server; rather, I believe it's going to be `www-data`. Is `www-data` supposed to reach across to `james` to access the virtualenv, or is there a way to install the virtualenv into `www-data`?  It seems like there should be a standardized way of configuring virtualenvs in production, but I can't seem to find anything.

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: I'd install the virtualenv into a directory "venv" in the project's root directory, rather than into a user's home directory. Then the setup can be the same in both prod and dev.

Comment: It is totally upto an individual's preference. My personal preference would be to create the virtualenv in `/usr/local/virtualenv/` - this way, it is a standard location irrespective of where the project actually resides on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can put the virtual environment at any place that suits you and can be read by the user running the python process. For security reasons you should consider to create the ve as an other user so the process has no write access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I always structure things like this:

virtualenvs:

```
/user/var/www/project/virtualenvs/myapp_env1
/user/var/www/project/virtualenvs/myapp_env2
/user/var/www/project/virtualenvs/myapp_env3
....
```

applications:

```
/user/var/www/project/applications/myapp1
/user/var/www/project/applications/myapp2
/user/var/www/project/applications/myapp3
...
```

I actually know that these things should not be under /var/www/ but I never paid attention to it..

and each app has its own user, named by appname.

Answer (score 0):

I setup my virtualenv in the same way you do.
What you should do is add `james` to the group `www-data` and it should be fine.

```
sudo adduser james www-data
```